# cloned form fields not submitting (no $_POST data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I have a form in a table with the option to duplicate a certain row (thus allowing users to add more fields as needed). The cloning works fine and the events data and handlers work fine. However when the form is submitted, the cloned form field data does not post. Below is my code for cloning the fields which works fine and solves any issue of duplicate IDs. Any suggestions/help as to why the cloned field do not submit would be absolutely appreciated.

```
$('#btnAddNewField').click(function() {
    var currLength = $('.cloneInput').length;   
    var newID = new Number(currLength + 1); 

    var clonedField = $('#field_id' + currLength).clone(true);  
    clonedField[0].setAttribute('id', 'field_id' + newID);      
    clonedField.find(':text').each(function() {                             
        this.setAttribute('id', this.getAttribute('id') + newID);               
        this.setAttribute('name', this.getAttribute('name') + newID);       
    });
    $('#field_id' + currLength).after(clonedField);
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="field_id_1">
    <td>
    <table>             
        <tr>
            <td>Pick option</td>
            <td> 
                <select name="choice_1" id="choice_1"  parent="true">
                    <option value="null" selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">option 3</option>             
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pick next option</td>
            <td> 
                <select name="next_choice_1" id="next_choice_1">
                    <option value="null" selected="selected">Select next</option>                
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>             
         <tr>
            <td>Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image_1" id="image_1"/></td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
    </td>                               
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> 
        <input type="button" value="Add New" id="btnAddNewField" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Remove" id="btnDelField" />
    </td>        
</tr>
```

Comment: Is the missing `'` from the `.find(':text)` a typo? Or is that error in your actual code? Hint: *look* at syntax-highlighting.

Comment: Have you seen the output HTML after this jQuery code executes? The cloned fielsd should have either Unique Name, OR, same name with `[]` appended, i.e. `foo[]`. Then all the values will be saved in `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`...`foo[index]` This approach also saves you from using a counter. As for unique IDs, you could use a `class` instead of `ID`..

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere where you are changing the name property of the cloned form fields.  You will need to change this in order to not have the posted data just overwritten by the additional fields.

Comment: I added the change to the name property of the cloned fields but still doesn't work. See updated code sample.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken by how post works. You should actualy create a new name for the cloned field, as that is what is used for posting the variables. Creating a new id is only nessecary to produce valid html, but has nothing to do with the actual posting.